# Javascript - removeChild removes a whole cell of a table

Tags: javascript

I have table where I can add new rows with input fields. Also there's a possibility to remove an added input field. Deleting a complete row works, but there's a problem to delete single input fields inside a cell.
Here's the code:

```
cell1=document.getElementById('avz_tabelle').rows[par.rowIndex].cells;

var feld = document.createElement("input"); 
feld.setAttribute("name","avz_keywords" + avz_array + "[]"); 
feld.setAttribute("onblur","");
feld.setAttribute("type","text"); 
feld.setAttribute("size","30"); 
cell1[1].appendChild(feld);

var remove = document.createElement("a");
remove.setAttribute("href","#");
remove.setAttribute("onclick","this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);");
remove.innerHTML = " X";
cell1[1].appendChild(remove);
var br = document.createElement("br");
cell1[1].appendChild(br);
```

The problem is that the remove action completly deletes the whole cell, instead of the related input field. The strange thing, that this works on the first tier of the table without problems. 
Do you see the error? Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you are appending the anchor element `remove` to `cell1[1]`, which is a single table cell of the row with index `par.rowIndex`. So the parentNode to the anchor element is the cell. With `this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)` you are removing the parentNode of the anchor, which is the cell.

EDIT: removed a sentence that might have been offensive ... sorry :-)

EDIT2: Possible solution:

```
this.previousSibling.parentNode.removeChild(this.previousSibling);
```

because `this.previousSibling` might be the input element

Comment: No, that was't offending, don't worry :-)

Yes the solution with this.previousSibling works, but it doesn't removes the "X"-Button. But thanks, this answer brings me one step further.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are building your HTML with the DOM, you don't have to set attributes for events:

replace `remove.setAttribute("onclick"...` by something like:

```
remove.onclick = function(ev){
  feld.parentNode.removeChild(feld);
}
```

`feld` and the `onclick` function are defined in the same scope, you have a closure here. It makes `feld` available inside the function.

Comment: This is a sexy solution, thank you very much!
If I add remove.innerHTML = ""; into the function it works perfectly. Woohoo.

Comment: @Crayl, it is not sexy, it is a way to get a clean an short code.